Upper bound on the condition number of the similarity transformation matrix
In the context of square matrices, we have been given
$$A = T\Lambda T^{-1}$$ where $\Lambda$ is a known diagonal matrix. It is also known that the condition number of A is bounded above. Say,
$$\kappa(A)\leq a$$
Can we find an upper bound on the condition of matrix $T$?

The matrix $T$ is unique only upto a scaling factor. Note that if $U = \alpha T$, then $A = U \Lambda U^{-1}$ still holds for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\setminus {0}$.

Agree! What if we have given an explicit form of matrix T?

If you have an explicit form of $T$, then you can use it to directly compute the condition number.

@sudeep5221, I appreciate your point. I thought of it. I was looking to see if I could somehow take the advantage of (1) the condition number of matrix A is bounded (2) the condition number of the diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ is known too. (3) the condition number of T and $T^{-1}$ is the same due to the property of the condition number of a matrix and its inverse.
